# How the differential cryptanalysis work?

Tags: cryptanalysis

I am new in the field of cryptanalysis and wonder how the differential cryptanalysis work

Answer (score 1):

You can check several resources about differential cryptanalysis. But there is a very well-explained tutorial about the topic which you can found at [Differential Cryptanalysis](http://www.theamazingking.com/crypto-diff.php). This tutorial uses a simple toy cipher to illustrate the idea, you can practice the attack on this toy cipher yourself.
You can then read about differential cryptanalysis on [Biham's paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00630563.pdf)

That's not a direct response to your question but I wanted to share these helpful resources as they helped me a lot.